# Colour points by x-axis values in ggplot

Tags: r

I have the following code to make a graph of my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

sdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58164604/sdata.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pdata<-melt(sdata, id.vars="Var")
p<-ggplot(pdata, aes(Var,value,col=variable))
p+geom_point(aes(shape = variable),alpha=0.7)
```

This creates a graph with 'Var' being the x-axis and 'value' being the y-axis.
What I would like to do is change how the points are coloured. Instead of being by the variable name, I would like them to be by their 'Var' value. So I would like all points that have a Var value between 1-10 to be one colour, 11-20 to be another, and so on for 21-30, 31-35 and 36-41. What I would also like is there to be a ribbon/area shaded behind these points that extends from the highest to lowest value for each Var value, but this ribbon would also have to have the same colour as the points, just with a lower transparency level.

For a bonus question I am also having trouble getting the 'mean' variable from my example to appear as a geom_line rather than a geom_point. I have been playing around with this:

```
 p+geom_point()+geom_line(data=pdata[which(pdata$variable=="Mean")])
```

but I can't get it to work. If anyone can help with any of this that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut` with options `labels=F`, I add a new variable for coloring.

```
pdata <- transform(pdata,varc =cut(pdata$Var,10,labels=F))
p<-ggplot(subset(pdata,variable!='Mean'), aes(Var,value,col=varc))
p+geom_point(aes(shape = variable),alpha=0.7)+
 geom_line(data=subset(pdata,variable =='Mean'),size=2)
```

**Edit:ribbon part**

I don't understand the part of the ribbon(maybe if you can more explain upper and lower values), but I think here we can simply use geom-polygon

```
last_plot()+ geom_polygon(aes(fill=varc, group=variable),alpha=0.3,linetype=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry that I did not make myself clearer. The data that I am using is 5 different categories, hence why I would like the ability to give all points from 1 to 10 a single colour, and 11 to 20 another colour and so on. To make this easier to see I was thinking of using the highest value for each Var (1 to 41), which is variable 5 and the lowest, variable 10 and shade them in the same colour as the points. So for the values of 1 to 10 there would be a shaded background of one colour, and then from 11 to 20 there would be another colour and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your first question, you can use the `cut` function to classify your continuous data into categories. For example:

```
with(mtcars, cut(mpg, seq(min(mpg), max(mpg), length = 5))
```

This cuts the continuous values in the `mpg` column into 5 classes.